# MySQL OPTIMIZE all tables

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm working on writing a lambda job in node js that runs optimize table query on weekly basis. Running a optimize query for a single table is feasible but not sure how to achieve iterative way of running the query for multiple tables. Kindly please suggest some steps.

Comment: Stored procedure. Cursor by INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES. Dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If your tables are using ENGINE=InnoDB, there is essentially no reason to run `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.

Comment: Does Innodb automatically takes care of optimizing the tables?

Comment: @Sakcan307 - It will combine two adjacent blocks that are less than half full.  It does not rebuild the entire BTree (as Optimize does).  For nearly all situations the former is "good enough".  Be aware, that random inserts into a BTree will leave some blocks between 50% and 100% full; the average is about 69%.  I consider this to be "good enough".  I consider rebuilding to be "not worth the effort", especially since it will quickly become "fragmented".